# How to get or set the Database character encoding when using PHP ODBC Functions?

Tags: php, character-encoding, odbc

If I use odbc functions to connect to a database in PHP, How can I get or set the database character encoding? is there a function in PHP that I can use to do that?

***An example of the odbc functions used in php script***

```
<?php

//Connecting To The Database and getting $conn Variable       
$conn = odbc_connect("database","username","password");

//Connection Check
if (!$conn)
{
echo "Database Connection Error: " . $conn;
}

$sqlResults = "SELECT EmpID AS EmployeeID, EmpName AS EmployeeName FROM Emp ORDER BY EmpName ASC";

$rsResults = odbc_exec($conn,$sqlResults);

if (!$rsResults)
{
echo "No Data Avialable";
}                                   
else
{

while ( odbc_fetch_row($rsResults) )
{

$EmployeeID   = odbc_result($rsResults,"EmployeeID");
$EmployeeName = odbc_result($rsResults,"EmployeeName");

//Printing the output
echo '<p>'. $EmpolyeeID . ' , ' . $EmployeeName . '</p>';              
}

}

//Closing The Database
odbc_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: You normally set the database encoding in the database itself. If you mean the database connection encoding, please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467145/character-encoding-issue-with-pdo-odbc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find information on this here at Rob Allens dev notes page

[rob allens dev notes](http://akrabat.com/php/utf8-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: Thanks for your usefual link and I hope I could find a solution for that in it.

Comment: The question was about ODBC and not for MySQL