# DB2 how to specify connection charset using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, db2

I'm looking for the DB2 translation of the following (and working) MySQL query:

```
SET NAMES 'UTF8'
```

I've connected to a DB2 using PDO_ODBC, and I can successfully query it, so it's not a connection problem.

The driver says that `NAMES` is an unexpected token, so I guess that there's another way to specify the connection charset.

I've searched stackoverflow but most of the answers are for mysql drivers, and I don't know what to search in the IBM documentation (which isn't the most friendly to navigate)

What I'm looking for is a SQL query that's acceptable by DB2 that has the same effect of MySQL's `SET NAMES xxx`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php refer to the manual.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks, but I'm looking for a DB2 equivalent of that MySQL setting.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.databaseskill.com/1720604/ it mentions "Listing 14 set the DB2 instance, make use utf-8
The $ Db2set db2codepage = 1208" - is that along the lines? Also http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.db.adapter.html that last one only has one mention of UTF-8 - see this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/3467145/

Comment: why you not use pdo Ibm ? (those are db2) as php.net says http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php pdo ibm connect to db2 and then use set attribute (names)

Comment: @MarcoMura thank you, but don't you think that set attribute should work even with basic ODBC? if so, what should I write to achieve that? I'll try to use PDO_IBM if everything else fails.

Comment: have seen this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467145/character-encoding-issue-with-pdo-odbc

Comment: Yes, i can't use `;charset=...` in the DSN because it seems not to be accepted.

Comment: You may use this then ->http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-setoption.php but then you need to check your odbc driver source for parameter.

Comment: That doesn't seem compatible with PDO, but rather with odbc_* functions

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve by this? There is no such thing as a _connection character set_ in DB2.

Comment: the point is, `SET NAMES xxx` is a SQL query. I'm looking for a compatible SQL query that's acceptable by DB2

Comment: It may come as a surprise, but not everyone may be as familiar with MySQL proprietary SQL as you. If you could explain what purpose does the `SET NAMES` serve in your case, some people may be able to offer a DB2 alternative.

Comment: @mustaccio you're right, sorry! here's a small extract from mysql docs: `SET NAMES indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL statements to the server. Thus, SET NAMES 'cp1251' tells the server, “future incoming messages from this client are in character set cp1251.” It also specifies the character set that the server should use for sending results back to the client.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is no equivalent statement in DB2.

DB2 client applications run using the standard operating system locale settings.  On UNIX/Linux this is set via the `LANG` environment variable (which may be overridden with various `LC_*` environment variables), and on Windows this is configured using the Control Panel.

On Linux/UNIX with PHP, this would mean that you would need to have the proper locale environment variables set up when your web server starts.

Notes:

- DB2 provides the option to override any operating system or environment-level setting using the `DB2CODEPAGE` registry variable.  This setting is at the DB2 client instance level, so it will affect any/all applications that connect using the DB2 client you've installed.
- If the client application codepage as determined by `LOCALE` differs from the database codepage, be aware that the DB2 client will perform code page conversion between the client codepage and the database codepage in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding in DB2 is set when the database is created. In order to insert the right characters in the database, it is necessary the application executes with the right encoding and that support it.

Comment: You need to configure your applications / terminal with the same encoding as the database. In order to get the encoding: db2 get db cfg

Answer (score 0):

I am using pdo_ibm and I found a way of correctly setting the charset as follows:

1) Make the following query through some manual means (DBeaver, etc.):

```sql
SELECT CODEPAGE FROM SYSCAT.DATATYPES WHERE TYPENAME = 'VARCHAR';
```

Make a note of the result. For example: 1208

2) You can now set this codepage by two different ways:

#### *The PHP Way*

```php
putenv('DB2CODEPAGE=1208');
```

First use this, then instantiate the PDO object.

#### *The OS Way*

(taken from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12102_01/books/AnyInstAdm784/AnyInstAdmPreInstall19.html)

For Windows:

- Navigate to Control Panel > System and click the Advanced tab. Click Environment Variables.
- In System variables section, click New.
- In the Variable Name field, DB2CODEPAGE.
- In the Variable Value field, enter the value that was returned in Step 1.

For UNIX, set the variable as shown below:

```sh
setenv DB2CODEPAGE <DB2CODEPAGE value>
```

For example: setenv 1208.

You may need to reboot the machine after creating the variable.